# AS3: Analyzing sound spectrums one by one, one channel at once

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio

I know the SoundMixer.computeSpectrum and Sound.extract() methods , but those methods deal with the total sound output.
Instead, is there a way to deal with every single SoundChannel, so as to provide a graphical visualization of each of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that's not possible. In fact, the computeSpectrum method doesn't even compute your own channels but analyses every sound the Flash plugin catches. This can be annoying when the sounds are playing on a different location which will cause crossdomain issues.

I guess you can best try to use and parse the Sound.extract() method.

hth