# Analyze sound by channels in flash player 11

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, audio, extract, spectrum

referring to my old question [AS3: Analyzing sound spectrums one by one, one channel at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416277/as3-analyzing-sound-spectrums-one-by-one-one-channel-at-once) , with flash player 11 and using Sound.extract,is it possible to extract a single channel and manipulate/visualize it's spectrum?

I mean, if i mix 2 sounds into one file, can i control them separately, acting on thing like their soundwaves or volume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Sound.extract you get raw sound data at 44100 Hz Stereo, which actually means two "channels".

If you merge two sounds into one file and  you want to process them individually you'll have to keep each one in its own channel, then you can programatically do anything  you want with them in isolation.

Note that you cannot use SoundMixer.computeSpectrum() to create visualizations as it's not currently allowed to do so dynamically (see API docs), you'll have to process the raw sound data yourself.